# Can we create a Jenkins Slave agent from other networks?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins Installed on my Local Mac and I am trying to setup a window Virtual machine created by AWS EC2 Instance and only accessbile via VPN. (Although I am also conneted to VPN on my local to access that machine). So in this scenario can I make my Virtual Machine of my local MAC??

Comment: "make my Virtual Machine of my local MAC" what do you mean?

Comment: @Iterokun it mean Virtual machine is a server hosted on AWS and could be accessible via VPN. Can I make this server  as jenkins slave agent of my Local Mac machine jenkins service(acting as master). 
On my local I'm connected to Vpn so I could access the server to which I want to make agent.

Comment: If you can connect from your Jenkins controller to the EC2 instance then yes, you can run a Jenkins agent on that instance. Just follow this guide https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/ and ask more specific questions.